# Best Practice for Config Variables on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, configuration, heroku

The Heroku docs suggest one way of managing config vars: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

I guess this works well for API keys, but seems clunky for other environment config info.

Are there any recommendations or better ways of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't ever found it clunky - but use heroku config vars for API keys and stuff which I don't want committed into a git repo and the relevant environment .rb file for application config stuff specific to each environment.

You can always https://github.com/fastestforward/heroku_san which lets you set config vars in a yml file which can be run against an app to set the vars without having to do it via the CLI

Answer (score 0):

[figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) is another gem which help us to manage this stuff.